# Ошибки с PHP7.0-FPM

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm, mariadb

**Что есть**: 2 сайта на Laravel 5.1;
Сервер Ububntu 16.04; nginx + php7 + php7.0-fpm + mariadb10.1 + redis

**Проблема**: Раз в сутки (перестает?) работать php7.0-fpm, при этом он продолжает отдавать php код, сайты открываются, но перестают работать некоторые функции.

Например **невозможно авторизоваться на сайте**, Lara пишет следующее в логах:local.ERROR: Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException

На другом сайте есть скрипт который использует CURL, запускается по крону каждые 10 минут, Lara пишет следующее: local.ERROR: RuntimeException: Could not resolve host

В логах NGINX и PHP-FPM **нет никаких ошибок** или даже предупреждений!
Все решается перезапуском PHP-FPM и работает следующие сутки без сбоев.
На следующий день все повторяется.

Как узнать, в чем же проблема? Как задетектить ошибки? Возможно кто то сталкивался?

**UPD:** 2 дня назад были обновлены все пакеты apt-get update && apt-get upgrade , после чего и начались проблемы

Comment: поднять error_log до debug и notice? и смотреть что куда пишеться и зацем

Comment: явно скрипт крона вешает php

Comment: @Naumov Да, поднял логи до debug, остается ждать.. Скрипт крона запускается каждые 10 минут, я не думаю что дело в нем, посмотрим

Comment: а есть скрипт который раз в сутки запускаеться?

Comment: Баги ежемесячных скриптов дебажить сложнее всего... Что мешает выполнить скрипт из крона вручную?

Comment: Скрипта, который запускается раз в сутки - нету, как и скрипта запускающегося раз в месяц. Есть только один скрипт, запускающийся раз в 10 минут. При его работе ошибок нет никаких. Этот скрипт просто генерирует рандомное число с помощью  defiant/randomorg для laravel. После последних изменений в коде (12 дней назад), это все работало без сбоев, началось 2 дня назад

Comment: UPD: 2 дня назад были обновлены все пакеты apt-get update && apt-get upgrade , после чего и начались проблемы

Comment: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data projectroot/storage`

Comment: такие ощущения что проблема с ajax или dns (http://)